# Taking a stationary phase approximation of a multidimensional integral

Tags: definite-integrals, approximation, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm looking for a way to take a stationary phase approximation of an integral of the following form:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty d\vec{q} \exp\left(2 \pi i N \left(S(q_{n+1}, \vec{q}, q_1) - \vec{K}^T\vec{q}\right)\right)$$

Here, $\vec{K}$ is just an integer valued constant vector, $\vec{q}$ is the vector $(q_2, q_3, \dotsc, q_n)$ and $S(q_{n+1}, \vec{q}, q_1)$ is just some scalar function that corresponds to the action of the system i'm looking at.

It has been suggested to me that this integral is highly oscillatory and thus the method of stationary phase can be utilised. However, I have no idea how to do stationary phase approximations for a multi-dimensional integral. Taking derivatives w.r.t $\,\vec{q}$ of the exponent suggests that stationary points occur when
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \vec{q}} = \vec{K}^T.$$
Given I can find these, what form would the stationary phase approximation take? Googling i've only been able to find references for 1-dimensional integrals, and at most a passing reference that the method can be extended to multi-dimensional integrals.

Comment: Can you include the context from which you're approaching this? A common source of such integrals (and for the need to approximate them) is in the path-integral formulation of quantum mechanics, where the stationary phase approximation amounts to finding the classical behavior.

Comment: It is indeed from quantum mechanics, quantum chaos in particular. The exact context is given in http://jpkeating.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/19.pdf on page 7 eq 2.9 and 2.10 :)

Comment: Ah, very nice. (My research interest has been in semiclassical analysis, though not in the field of quantum chaos.) You might find the discussion of the Feynman path integral in Chapter 3 of Altland & Simons ("Condensed Matter Field Theory") useful. It discusses the stationary phase approximation nicely, and it closes the chapter with some discussion of quantum chaos (including a derivation of the Gutzwiller trace formula via stationary phase!)

Comment: Also, since that is indeed the context, it wouldn't hurt to edit your question accordingly; that includes using the math.-physics and quantum-mech. tags.